# jQuery validate error message misplaced

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have more that one text boxes with same name and class. I use jQuery validate to validate it as required. Issue here is when I submit the form without entering values for fields other than 1st check box, error messages are showing next to first textbox.
For example if I submit form without entering values for 2nd textbox, it will show error message near to first text box. I think it is because of using same name/class for validation.

I have tried using class and name. No change. My sample code is given below. Any thoughts?

HTML part

```
<input type="text" class="unit_price" name="add_purch_unit[]">
<input type="text" class="unit_price" name="add_purch_unit[]">
```

jQuery Part

```
$(".unit_price").rules("add", { 
        required:true
    });
```

Comment: it is because of the same name...

Comment: But I use class here to validate

Comment: that is to add the rule... but internally the validator framework used element name

Comment: So, any idea to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".unit_price").rules("add", { 
    required:true
});
```

Two problems with your code.

1. You cannot attach a jQuery Validate method to a jQuery selector that targets more than one element.  The solution for this part is to wrap the method within a jQuery `.each()`.

   ```
   $(".unit_price").each(function() {
       $(this).rules("add", { 
           required:true
       });
   });
   ```
2. However, you still cannot duplicate the `name` attribute.  Even though we solved the problem from #1 above to assign the rule to every element with `class="unit_price"`, the plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of all input elements.  The solution is that you *must* also assign a unique `name` to each element... there is no workaround for this requirement.

   ```
   <input type="text" class="unit_price" name="add_purch_unit[1]">
   <input type="text" class="unit_price" name="add_purch_unit[2]">
   ```

Comment: Exactly what I was writing in my post, so I will just support this one and you should go with it too.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky .each also does same thing. I have tested that too. Anyway I have to use different names.

Comment: @Corner, no, `.each()` works fine ***only*** as long as you have unique `name` attributes.  In other words, I did not provide you with two different solutions.  No matter how you assign the rules, you must have unique `name` attributes.